# Return next page of results over file_limit

Tags: dropbox-api

The [search docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#search) say that the maximum number of results is 1000. If I hit that, is there any way to return the next page of results?

Answer (score 1):

No.

(adding more text to appease Stack Overflow)

Comment: An alternative here may be to use /delta and filter the entries client-side: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta